# Can I be sure that this temporary variable won't be optimized away?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, optimization, dispatcher

Something happens in my system on a worker thread. Let's say that the **state** changes. I want to handle the new **state** in the UI thread, so I dispatch a delegate to be invoked there:

```
var state = GetState();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => StateChanged(state));
```

When `StateChanged` executes on the UI thread, can I then be sure that the value of the parameter `state` is the value returned by `GetState()` **before** the dispatch, or will the temporary `state` variable be optimized away so that `GetState()` is called on the UI thread to populate the `StateChanged` parameter?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of _closures_.  That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I then be sure that the value of the parameter state is the value
>   returned by GetState() **before** the dispatch or will the temporary state variable be optimized > away

No `state` won't be optimized away. 
However, **Before** is actually the tricky part about this question. As long as you are not changing the state variable **after** (in the same scope) you have nothing to worry about.

```
{
 // say GetState returns 2
 var state = GetState(); 
 // state now = 2
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => StateChanged(state)); 
 state = 3; 
}
```

In the code above `state` won't be optimized away. It does not mean, however, that `StateChanged` will be invoked with value 2. It could be 3, if the worker thread completes execution before starting the dispatcher thread.

The main point here is that variable capturing insures that the value is preserved for the use of the closure, but that does not mean that the value is immutable.

Answer (score 4):

No, `GetState` will definitely be called on the worker thread. An "optimization" to move the `GetState()` call within the lambda expression would be entirely invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This will not happen as it would change the semantics of the operations, optimizations are not allowed to do that; you make an assignment to a variable by calling a method, so because C# is not a lazy language this *will* have to happen at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
var state = GetState();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => StateChanged(state));
```

is fine. But this variation would be much more difficult to analyze and prove correct:

```
var state = GetState();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => StateChanged(state));  // after GetState()
state = null;                       // before or after StateChanged() ?
```

Comment: Slaks is right - with this code StateChanged will always see `state==null`. I was thinking about a Thread.

Comment: A thread would have exactly the same issue.  @JohannGerell: Henk explained it perfectly.